# Avocado pruning, fertilizing and repotting advice

Tags: pruning, fertilizer, avocado, repotting

My very leggy avocado plant is about 1 meter tall and seems to be suffering from chlorosis. I think I need to prune it to make it more bushy, fertilize it and repot it. In what order should I do these things and how much time should I wait between each action?

I live in Spain on the Mediterranean coast. The climate is subtropical. We have hot summers and mild winters.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: The main problem seems to be lack of sun. could you add some information about location and sun? Is it in a terrace? Facing south? Or Indoor?

Comment: This is not its usual place. I wanted to photograph it without other plants behind it. It is on a bright outdoor terrace facing southwest. It gets direct sun in the summer from about 12 noon to 5 pm.